# Passing return pointer to another pointer in C leads in garbage or lost data?

Tags: c, pointers

Can anyone help me understand why this is not working how I would expect? Not sure why my return value gets truncated when I try to assign the value to a new pointer.

CODE

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char *getname(){
    char *name;
    printf("Please enter your name: ");
    scanf("%s", &name);
    printf("The value being returned is: %s\n", &name);
return name;
}

int main(){
    char *name;
    name = getname();
    printf("The value in main function: %s\n",&name);
return 0;
}
```

OUTPUT

```
Please enter your name: test1234
The value being returned is: test1234
The value in main function: test�
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use the ampersand (`&`) when you pass a pointer to `scanf` with "%s". `&` takes the address of its operand. A pointer is already an address.

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to explain that to me, i really appreciate it.

Answer (score 3):

You should allocate memory in `getname` and free the memory in `main`.
The ampersand isn't needed in the scanf or printf.
%79s prevents overwriting the memory allocated for name.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char *getname(){
    char *name = malloc ( 80);
    if ( name == NULL) {
        printf ( "malloc failed\n");
        return NULL;
    }
    printf("Please enter your name: ");
    scanf("%79s", name);
    printf("The value being returned is: %s\n", name);
    return name;
}

int main(){
    char *name;
    name = getname();
    if ( name == NULL) {
        return 1;
    }
    printf("The value in main function: %s\n",name);
    free ( name);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have not allocated memory for `char *name`. Add the following line after 'name' declaration.

```
name = (char *)malloc(80);
```

After using this in main just call

```
free(name);
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you should be printing a string like the following:
    printf("The value being returned is: %s\n", name);

The `%s` format specifier expects a `char*`, not a `char**`.

`char *name` declares a variable which is a pointer that stores the address of a `char`. This variable just out of your luck may contain a valid memory address, to which you are trying to write your string. That could be the reason you are getting some kind of output from your `printf`.

You should allocate enough memory for your string to occupy and point `name` to that memory before writing to it. Use of unallocated memory results in *undefined behavior*. You can have no guarantee of what will happen. The program may even unsuspectingly appear to work flawlessly or crash immediately. You can use `malloc`, `calloc` etc to allocate memory on the heap. See [this output of the same code](http://ideone.com/6yozya), and I am sure you will find the program behaving differently.

On a tangential note, it's not a good practice to use unsafe functions like `scanf()`. You would be better off using `fgets()`; and `sscanf()` if you require to parse the input.